# WinrtTrigger to change grid visibility

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, triggers

I am using this xaml to control visibility of grid on loaded event.

```
    <Grid Grid.RowSpan="2" x:Name="grdStartup">
        <trigger:Interactions.Triggers>
            <trigger:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded" >                    
                <trigger:SetPropertyAction PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </trigger:EventTrigger>
        </trigger:Interactions.Triggers>
    </Grid>
```

This is not working, no error and no result.
Right now it's collapsed but later on I'll bind it to some property.

Comment: Why not just set its `Visibility="Collapsed"` as the default since you want it like that onload anyway? The trigger seems redundant.

Comment: I used collapsed just for testing. On load I have to bind its visibility with a viewmodel property. And after that its visibility managed by a storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps. for more details [Visit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.eventtrigger)

```
    <Grid x:Name="Gd" Visibility="Visible">
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Gd" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="Collapsed" KeyTime="0"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
    </Grid>
```